# I am not able to remove elements from the list

Tags: python

The task that I have to do is showing all other elements rather than (Americano). I tried to use 'Record.remove("Americano") but it shows the error

```
Record.remove("Americano")
ValueError: list.remove(x): x not in list
```

What should I Do......

=========================this is the result of=======================     Record.append(record[1]) print(Record) ->

```
['Menu_name', 'Cafe_latte', 'Americano', 'Americano', 'Smoothie_queen', 'Americano', 'Americano', 'Cafe_mocha', 'Cafe_latte', 'Americano', 'Amorparty', 'Plain_yogurt', 'Americano', 'Americano', 'Cafe_mocha', 'Berry_smoothie', 'Cafe_mocha', 'Cafe_latte', 'Americano', 'Cafe_latte', 'Berry_smoothie', 'Berry_smoothie', 'Plain_yogurt', 'Berry_smoothie', 'Plane_yougurt', 'Berry_smoothie', 'Cafe_latte', 'Americano', 'Americano', 'Cafe_mocha', 'Plain_yogurt', 'Americano', 'Plain_yogurt', 'Cafe_mocha', 'Plain_yogurt', 'Americano', 'Cofe_latte', 'Plain_yogurt', 'Cafe_mocha', 'Americano', 'Berry_smoothie', 'Cafe_latte', 'Cafe_latte', 'Cafe_mocha', 'Cafe_latte', 'Cafe_latte', 'Cafe_mocha', 'Americano', 'Plain_yogurt', 'Americano', 'Americano', 'Cofe_latte', 'Berry_smoothie', 'Berry_smudie', 'American_air', 'Plain_yogurt', 'Berry_smoothie', 'Berry_smoothie', 'Berry_smoothie', 'Cafe_latte', 'Americano', 'Plain_yogurt', 'Cafe_latte', 'Cafe_mocha', 'Cafe_mocha', 'Plain_yogurt', 'Berry_smoothie', 'Berry_smoothie', 'Cafe_mocha', 'Cafe_mocha', 'Berry_smoothie', 'Cafe_mocha', 'Plain_yogurt']
```

---

```
def load_menu():
    Menu = []
    #========= STEP 1 ==========
    menufile = open("menu.txt", "r")

    for line in menufile:
        menu = line.split()
        Menu.append(menu)

    menufile.close()

    for menu in Menu:
        print(menu[0]," : ",menu[1])
    #========= STEP 1 ==========
    return Menu

def error_check(date):
    #========= STEP 3 ==========
    Record = []
    recordfile = open("ledger_"+date+".txt","r")

    for line in recordfile:
        record = line.split()
        Record.append(record[1])
        Record.remove("Americano")
    print(Record)

    recordfile.close()
    #========= STEP 3 ==========
```

Answer (score 2):

```py
ValueError: list.remove(x): x not in list
```

You have error because list Record don't have "Americano" in Record.

You should check record is not 'Americano' before add it to Record

Try this:

```py
def error_check(date):
    #========= STEP 3 ==========
    Record = []
    recordfile = open("ledger_"+date+".txt","r")

    for line in recordfile:
        record = line.split()[1]
        if record != "Americano":
            Record.append(record)
    print(Record)
    recordfile.close()
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use:

```
def error_check(date):
    #========= STEP 3 ==========
    Record = []
    recordfile = open("ledger_"+date+".txt","r")

    for line in recordfile:
        record = line.rstrip().split()
        Record.append(record[1])
        Record.remove("Americano")
    print(Record)

    recordfile.close()
```

Comment: The ledger_date.txt file contains such informations

No. Menu_name Num Total 
1 Cafe_latte 8 20000
2 Americano 11 22000
3 Americano 7 14000
4 Smoothie_queen 4 12000
5 Americano 2 4000

The thing that I have to do is showing other elements than Americano except numbers. That is the reason why I have used "Record.append(record[1])". I have tried your answer but it still shows the same error...

Answer (score 0):

You should check if "Americano" in list before remove the element:

```
def error_check(date):
    #========= STEP 3 ==========
    Record = []
    recordfile = open("ledger_"+date+".txt","r")

for line in recordfile:
    record = line.split()
    Record.append(record[1])
    if "Americano" in Record:
        Record.remove("Americano")
print(Record)

recordfile.close()
#========= STEP 3 ==========
```